# Is it possible for my custom input not to work in shadow-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shadow-dom, custom-component

I have a very simple react component with input:

```
const Search = ({ onchange, t }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log('value', value);
  }, [value]);

  return (
      <div className={'user-search'}>
          <input
              placeholder={t('placeholder')}
              className={'search-input'}
              onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
              type="text"
          />
          <div className={'search-icon'}>
              <icon className={'icon'} size={'normal'} name="search" />
          </div>
      </div>
  );
```

};

At the same time, I use a library with client components - **most of them create a shadow-root in the DOM**. Nevertheless, I can drop my components inside them via {children} or sometimes props.

Well, and I have a problem with this Search component: when I use it loosely anywhere in the project I get a console.log with "value" after typing something in the input. On the other hand, **when I put it into the component with modal and accordion** (from the client library) - **input completely stops working and doesn't respond.**

**Could the non-functioning input have something to do with shadow-dom? Or do I need to provide more information?**

Comment: I still don't get the point why ```useEffect()``` is included, containing a text input in the dependency array. ? Can it not be covered in the ```OnChangeEvent()``` only ??

Comment: useEffect() is there only for me, and will be deleted later - it’s should console.log value for me each time it has been updated. Its not problem with useEffect

Comment: If you need to only console.log the input on change, then use the onchange event itself it is much more efficient. Why are you re rendering the whole UI ?

Comment: I can suggest you that, maybe create a new function that can be used for handling the ```onChange()``` event, And that can actually help you achieve you the necessary, AS you have not stated why you have used ```useEffect()``` and ***re-rendering the UI again***